# I'm want to get the location by putting a Woeid(Python 3)

Tags: python, woe-id

I need to get the location by introducing a woeid and i don't know how can i do it something like

`woeid=23424977` then returns me United States

Comment: Does this help? http://woeid.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example.html#example-6-retrieving-a-place-using-a-given-woeid